# In Notepad++ Is there a way to insert data from the second column into the first

Tags: sorting, notepad++

I have these documents that I need to sort the data from and convert them to a different format. Each document has over 1k lines so you can see why I need help. I have organized the data into column 1 and column 2. I need to insert the data in column 2 above column 1 and merge them. Let me show you an example.

I have this now set up in columns:

```
5939 99 22         #Static 3789                     
                   
5960 227 28        #Static 3619                     
                   
5942 102 22        #Static 4337                     
                   
5987 83 0          #Static 7395
```

and I need to format it to look like this. Using the line in the right column twice once with a # and once without. Is this possible or close to possible? If so how would I accomplish this in Notepad++ or maybe some other software?

```
#Static 3789 
Static 3789 
5939 99 22

#Static 3619
Static 3619
5960 227 28        

#Static 4337 
Static 4337          
5942 102 22 

#Static 7395  
Static 7395  
5987 83 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a find and replace, in regex mode.  The approach below is to match the leading 3-digit component and static component in separate capture groups.  Then, build the replacement using these capture groups.

```
Find:    (\d+ \d+ \d+)\s+#(Static \d+)
Replace: #$2\n$2\n$1
```

### Demo

Comment: Wow Tim you really know your stuff! This is a huge help! Thank you so much. One last question. In this formula everything works great except for lines that have a negative number. Like this one: 6080 146 -7        #Static 1957. They are unaffected by the search and replace and the data remains separated. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: @Aaron Change the find pattern to include optional negatives: `(-?\d+ -?\d+ -?\d+)\s+#(Static \d+)` ... I would rather not change my answer though, since your sample data did not reveal this edge case.

Comment: Yes you answered the question correctly I left out this bit of information Thank you again.